# Hiding an api key, php

Tags: javascript, php, api-key

I'm trying to hide my api key, so it is no accessible for quota reasons. The api just retrieves data that is recipes, so no credit card details etc is going on.

Ive been working on this for the past few days all day/night since Im pretty new to php, but it seemed stackoverflow in general was saying there needs to be some sort of proxy.
This is what I created and I would like to know if it is secure enough.

```
App.js
// I make an axios post request to script.php, passing along a 'searchfield' value. Lets say its "apples"

script.php
// receives the 'searchfield' value, then initiates a curl request to the api with my keycode/searchfield etc.
// This returns the response for apples which is an array of objects back to App.js
```

my script.php looks along the lines of this, anything Im missing?

```
$ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://fake.com?api_key=1234';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: _"secure enough"_ for what? Right now a user won't see the api-key, but still anybody could use script.php unless you have a login system involved.

Comment: This is very unclear: "I'm trying to hide my api key, so it is no accessible for quota reasons." Hide it from whom? If you need to use it in your request, there's no way to hide it from the target website. Also, if you're violating the terms of the API, that's an issue to take up with whomever provides the API, not an issue to wire around like this. (You'll just get your IP blocked.) If you're trying to hide it from *users of your site*, it's already not visible.

Comment: I am trying to hide it, since post I read said to not store the api on the client side, since its easily visible. I dont want someone to be able to grab my api key, use it and destroy my quota.

Comment: Rather than hitting the API endpoint for every request, cache the response.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to hide an API key from users...couldn't someone look at the post request and get the key using this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is on the PHP Side of things which is a Server Side Language and is not viewable from the outside world you are good to go on the security thing as long you do have a user system in place. If you don't they can abuse this api key by just calling your file.

So leaving the security way of things, it would be wise to store your api key to a constant, so on future requests you won't have to type it again, and in case you request a change of your api key, you won't have to change it from everywhere.

There are also good libraries for consuming REST APIs, which you can search on the web.